# Cannot declare class App\Utils\System\Log because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 & PHP Version 5.6.21 and have come across the issue :

> FatalErrorException in Log.php line 8: Cannot declare class
>   App\Utils\System\Log because the name is already in use
>
> ```
> in Log.php line 8
> ```

My Log.php looks like this :

```
<?php namespace App\Utils\System;

use Log;
use App\Log as LogDB;
use Carbon\Carbon as Carbon;

class Log
{
    public function save($msg,$flag)
    {
        /*
        //check to see if there is an organisation set
        $org = '';
        if(!is_null(session('organisation_name')))
        {
            $org = session('organisation_name');
        }

        $message ='{"action":"'.$msg.'", "uuid":"'.\Auth::user()->id.'", "company_id":"'.\Auth::user()->company_id.'","Organisation":"'.$org.'","Date":"'.Carbon::now().'"}';
        //set a local log
        if($flag=='info')
            Log::info($message);
        //save to the DB
        $l = new LogDB();
        $l->log_message = $message;
        $l->save();
        */
    }
}
```

The problem, I'm finding is, If I rename log to anything else, I always get the error...

Has anyone had this issue? Any fixes known.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Chay22 I've ran dump autoload a couple of times - No dice :-(

Comment: I see some light. Use alias?

Comment: Hi @Chay22 can you explain further?

Comment: @Chay22 Thank you for your help. Sussed it by doing the following :

use function Log as Log;